# Scalar function calculation

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to sum the contents of two variables in a scalar function and I want to use the outcome of this calculation in a string. However, the script does not return the value 10 in the table. What am I doing wrong?

```
Alter FUNCTION [dbo].[_KOptionsPounds] ()
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
     Declare @test int=5
     Declare @test2 int=5
     Declare @output nvarchar(max)
     Declare @testcalc int

     select @testcalc = @test + @test2

     set @output='<table><tr><td>£'+@testcalc+'</td></tr></table>'

RETURN @output
END
```

Comment: The error message when you call it isn't a hint?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace one line to:

```
 set @output='<table><tr><td>£'+convert(nvarchar(10), @testcalc)+'</td></tr></table>'
```

Comment: 10 is not long enough. the max value of int (`2147483647`) will fit in a 10 chars long string, but the min value (`-2147483648`) needs 11.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server (based on the syntax) -  You should be getting an error -

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '`<table><tr><td>£`' to data type int.

That's because when you try to concatenate an int to string, SQL server will try to implicitly convert the string to an int and add it to the other int.
You need to cast the int value to a string:

```
set @output='<table><tr><td>£' + CAST(@testcalc as nvarchar(11)) + '</td></tr></table>'4
```